# discord.js | Adding a role to a member on a server

Tags: discord.js

I need a code like the one below. I searched a lot, but none of them work. Can you help me ?

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQROg.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The fix is simple as per your code you have passed it has a number , instead you should pass it as a string

```js
client.guilds.cache.get('server id').members.cache.get('member id').roles.add('role id');
```